# How to insert child without updating the parent in EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent object. I want to insert the child object without updating the parent in entity framework core 3.0.

```html
Parent = context.Table1.AsNoTracking()                    
                    .Include(s => s.Table2).AsNoTracking()                    
                    .Include(s => s.Table3).ThenInclude(y=>y.Table4).ThenInclude(s=>s.Table5).ThenInclude(x => x.Table6).ThenInclude(s => s.Table7).ThenInclude(s => s.Table9).AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(s => s.Table10).AsNoTracking()                                  
                    .Where(somecondition).AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(t => new Table1
                    {
                      Id= Table1.Id,
                      Name=Table1.Name
                      Property3=t.Property3.Select(s=> new Table3{...}).ToList();
            
            
                    }
```

The parent table has multiple child tables and has a few image data which is not needed, So I get the list of fields I need by using the above logic.

At some point in code, I need to insert a few child objects into a table - Table12.

```html
Table12.ParentId= iParentId;
Table12.Name="TestName";
Table12.Value="TestValue";
context.Entry(Table12).State = EntityState.Added;
context.Entry(Table12.Parent).State = EntityState.Unchanged;//Tried detached as well-not working
 await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem is the insert on Table12 tries to update Table1 with parent object that has null values for the fields I don't need. Please suggest me how to insert only the child with parentId

Comment: How do you know the parent table is being updated?

Comment: I checked in sql profiler. The generated query tries to update related entities and hence it fails due to the validations on other child tables.

Comment: which fields do the query try to update? If you haven't changed anything in that parent row there should be no field to update... Are you sure the update comes from the child insert? I sincerely doubt it.

Comment: I changed a few properties of the parent before the insert. I am sure the update comes from the child. When I created the parent, I didn't create with all its properties. The same for parent.property2, parent.property3 and properties of parent.property3,etc. So parent object has multiple fields different from the one in db. The code also changes a few properties of the parent after that. The query on profiler was big and it was trying to update multiple tables table2,table3,etc

Comment: Well, if you changed properties on the parent then it's normal it tries to update it... try to add `context.GetChangeSet().Updates.Clear();` before you create the new item, this will clear any update operations pending on the context.

Comment: Insert  `Table12.Parent = null;` before `Table12.ParentId= iParentId;`  and remove `context.Entry(Table12.Parent).State =  ...` line.

Comment: GetChangeSet() is not available in EF core. assigning null to Parent was throwing exception on Save.

Comment: The below solution worked.
var changedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified ||e.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();
foreach (var entry in changedEntries)
 entry.State = EntityState.Detached;

Comment: Messing around with detached entities like this is chasing the white rabbit down the hole. Before long it will be "Why, oh why didn't I take the blue pill." Entities should always reflect the complete, or complete-able (lazy proxy) data state. Populating partial representations to pass around will mean constant second-guessing within any method accepting an entity, did I get a "real" entity" or some half-baked one. It's similar to violating Liskov's Substitution Principle. If a caller is expecting an entity, it should get an entity. Good luck though seeing how far the rabbit hole goes. :)